# How to add Mentions programmatically in jquery-mentions-input

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery-mentions-input to Add Mention Users in post.Its working Fine.But I am having an option to edit an post and I want all the mention previously added in post to load in textarea,just like they did at time of adding post.

But I am unable to Add these mentions programmatically  again in Textbox.I have all the UserId and userName in an Array.

I have used this Method but it says addMentiondoesn't Exists.

```
$("#txteditbox").mentionsInput('addMention',userName, id, type);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to this link: https://github.com/podio/jquery-mentions-input/pull/37 and download the jquery.mentionsInput at this location, which added function 'addmention', thus it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add prepopulate attribute with json data

```
$("#txteditbox")tokenInput("controller/token.php", {

    theme: "facebook",
    hintText: "",
    preventDuplicates: true,
    tokenLimit: 5,
    minChars: 2,
    placeholder:"Enter tag by which anybody can search this task",

    prePopulate:[
        {id: 123, name: "Slurms MacKenzie"},
        {id: 555, name: "Bob Hoskins"},
        {id: 9000, name: "Kriss Akabusi"}
           ],

            ...........
            ...........
```